# Mongoid: Querying for documents for certain fields which contains a given string

Tags: mongoid

I am a little stuck here (mongoid docs does not seem to give an answer)

```
Question.where(:text.contains=>"perfect")
```

I would like to find questions which text field contains a given word, in this case, perfect.

What is the correct query here, and how can i improve the performance of such queries?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should be able to use simple regex for that:

```
Question.where(:text => /perfect/)
```

Alex

Comment: thank you! if i perform indexing on this field, would this query be fast as well?

Comment: well, running a regex (it's a javascript engine) will always for slower than not, but I have not ran into any particular issue with this type of query even on relatively large collection